# Run sql query in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I imported one table of my mysql database to an excel spreadsheet, with one of the columns I created a dropdrown list to be able to choose frojm the imported table. My question is how do I show another attribute from the selected item.

I tried methods to do it in excel but these methods doesn't work because the item is choosen from a list

I tough a query like this would work because I am very new to excel but I know a bit of sql

```
SELECT x 
FROM mytable 
WHERE id1= 'y'
```

Comment: Needs more detail - exactly *how* did you create a drop-down list, and what methods did you already try?

Comment: I created the dropdown list with the data validation option

Comment: Start by  SELECT *  FROM mytable WHERE id1 = 'y'  ;;; just to see your column names and then use a comma separated list of the columns instead of the asterisk.

Comment: The problem, is not the query , the problem is that I don't know to do it in excel

Comment: @arluy288 Correct me if wrong/fill in the blanks -> Both the data and the dropdown are on the same sheet named ___.  The data has columns A thru ___ with column headings __ (paste in  sample rows 1..4  in your orig question area). The dropdown is in cell __ __ and references column __. Where should the selected attribute(s) be shown? which cells? or on another sheet, named ___?  What would the output look like?